# Qt Problems Adding Table Widget Items

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have an invoice form which i am using to both create invoices and display the results of a stored invoice. I when i am trying to read back data from the database and display it i am getting the error of

> QTableWidget: cannot insert an item that is already owned by another QTableWidget
>   QTableWidget: cannot insert an item that is already owned by another QTableWidget
>   QTableWidget: cannot insert an item that is already owned by another QTableWidget
>   QTableWidget: cannot insert an item that is already owned by another QTableWidget
>   QTableWidget: cannot insert an item that is already owned by another QTableWidget

I don't understand why this is being cause. The query that i am trying to run will return 4 rows. My code is below

```
QString CompanyID;
            int row = 0;
            ui->comboBox_Invoice_Account_Search->setCurrentIndex(1);
            QSqlQuery Account_Name_Query;
            QTableWidgetItem *Qty_Search = new QTableWidgetItem();
            QTableWidgetItem *Description_Search = new QTableWidgetItem();
            QTableWidgetItem *Product_Code_Search = new QTableWidgetItem();
            QTableWidgetItem *Unit_Price_Search = new QTableWidgetItem();
            QTableWidgetItem *Total_Price_Search = new QTableWidgetItem();
            while(Query.next())
            {
                CompanyID = Query.value(10).toString();
                //qDebug() << "CompanyID " << CompanyID;
                ui->lineEdit_Invoice_VAT->setText(Query.value(9).toString());
                ui->lineEdit_Invoice_Total->setText(Query.value(8).toString());
                ui->lineEdit_Goods_Total->setText(Query.value(7).toString());
                Qty_Search->setText(Query.value(3).toString());
                Description_Search->setText(Query.value(4).toString());
                Product_Code_Search->setText(Query.value(5).toString());
                Unit_Price_Search->setText(Query.value(6).toString());
                Total_Price_Search->setText(Query.value(7).toString());
                ui->tableWidget_Invoice->setItem(row, 0, Qty_Search);
                ui->tableWidget_Invoice->setItem(row, 1, Description_Search);
                ui->tableWidget_Invoice->setItem(row, 2, Product_Code_Search);
                ui->tableWidget_Invoice->setItem(row, 3, Unit_Price_Search);
                ui->tableWidget_Invoice->setItem(row, 4, Total_Price_Search);
                row++;
                Account_Name_Query.prepare("SELECT Company_Name FROM Customer WHERE Company_ID = '"+ CompanyID +"'");
                Account_Name_Query.exec();
                while(Account_Name_Query.next())
                {
                    ui->lineEdit_Invoice_Account->setText(Account_Name_Query.value(0).toString());
                }
            }
```

what is causing this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you are trying to set the same items you created outside of loop into the same table multiple times. Change your code to:

```
while(Query.next())
{
    QTableWidgetItem *Qty_Search = new QTableWidgetItem();
    QTableWidgetItem *Description_Search = new QTableWidgetItem();
    QTableWidgetItem *Product_Code_Search = new QTableWidgetItem();
    QTableWidgetItem *Unit_Price_Search = new QTableWidgetItem();
    QTableWidgetItem *Total_Price_Search = new QTableWidgetItem();

    ...
}
```